# Server Check Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My redirect and server check not working for my index.php in codeigniter.

I have a front end install wizard for codeigniter with 4 steps the 4th step being the last. I am trying to make it so if user has gone through the steps and has reached step 4 that will have access to website on there domain/server.

Currently the code I use keeps on redirecting to the index.php of my install URL, even though I have completed all steps.

This code below is on my main index.php

```
if (!file_exists('install/index.php')) {

// Make sure we've not already tried this
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/install/')) {
header('Status: 404');
exit;
}

// Otherwise go to installer
header('Location: '.rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/').'/install/');
exit;
}
```

Welcome Controller

```
public function index()
    {

        if (!file_exists('install/index.php')) {

        // Make sure we've not already tried this
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/install/')) {
        header('Status: 404');
        exit;
        }

        // Otherwise go to installer
        header('Location: '.rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/').'/install/');
        exit;
        } else {

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place this code in the `welcome controller`

Place your code inside the index function of the controller

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        /* your redirect code*/ 
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        echo 'Look at this!';
    }
}
```